# object has no attribute, Python crash course

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class GameStats. In that I have a method ship_left. I am trying to run it from within the same object context. this method supposed to change the number of ship's remain in the game after collide between alien and ship.

I tried to change the argument in few ways but its kept coming with the message AttributeError: 'GameStats' object has no attribute 'ship_left'.

**Please have a look at the code:**

```
class GameStats():
    """Track statistics for alien invasion."""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings):
        """Initialize statistics."""
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.reset_stats()

        # Start game in an inactive state.
        self.game_active = False

    def reset_stats(self):
        self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
```

I have define ship_left in another window:

```
def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):

    """Respond to ship being hit by alien."""
    if stats.ship_left >= 0:
        # Decrement ship_left.
        stats.ship_left -= 1

        # Empty the list of aliens and bullets.
        aliens.empty()
        bullets.empty()

        # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
        create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
        ship.center_ship()

        # Pause
        sleep(0.5)
    else:
        stats.game_active = False
```

Comment: `I have a method ship_left. I am trying to run it` - where is the method and where is "you trying to run it"???

Comment: Are you dynamically setting that method in `reset_stats` and are just having a typo there: `ships_left`?

Comment: `I have define ship_left in another window` - that's `ship_hit` as far as the eye can tell.

Comment: I meant...  stats.ship_left -= 1

when i try to run the game i'm working on this is the message i get:
AttributeError: 'GameStats' object has no attribute 'ship_left'

Comment: I see `if stats.ship_left...`. Where is `stats.ship_left` initialized prior to this statement. And why did you claim that it's a method in the first place, when it is clearly a variable???

Comment: I'm doing this clash course for python beginner. this code is build up in the course. 
maybe i don't use the right names as you asked why did i claim that it's a method

Comment: I think @schwobaseggl was right. The attribute in `GameStats` is `ships_left`, and you're referencing `ship_left` in the `ship_hit()` function. Change `ship_left` in `ship_hit()` to `ships_left`, and things should work.

Answer (score 0):

Aye,
it`s typo - should be "self.stats.ships_left > 0" etc